# Can you capture the output of ipython's magic methods? (timeit)

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, timeit

I want to capture and plot the results from 5 or so `timeit` calls with logarithmically increasing sizes of *N* to show how `methodX()` scales with input.

So far I have tried:

```
output = %timeit -r 10 results = methodX(N)
```

It does not work...

Can't find info in the docs either.  I feel like you should be able to at least intercept the string that is printed.  After that I can parse it to extract my info.

Has anyone done this or tried?

PS: this is in an ipython notebook if that makes a diff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture the result of an IPython magic function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289437/capture-the-result-of-an-ipython-magic-function)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This duplicate question [Capture the result of an IPython magic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289437/capture-the-result-of-an-ipython-magic-function) has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25289938/982257) demonstrating that this has since been implemented.

Calling the `%timeit` magic with the `-o` option like:

```
%timeit -o <statement>
```

returns a `TimeitResult` object which is a simple object with all information about the `%timeit` run as attributes.  For example:

```
In [1]: result = %timeit -o 1 + 2
Out[1]: 10000000 loops, best of 3: 23.2 ns per loop

In [2]: result.best
Out[2]: 2.3192405700683594e-08
```

Comment: This seems specific to only some magic commands (maybe just `%timeit`?).  It does not work with `%%timeit`.  Using `result = %%timeit -o` as the line of a cell returns `None`.

Comment: @StevenC.Howell You can use `%%timeit -o` without assignment. It will return a `TimeitResult`  object and thanks to IPython's output capture you can retrieve the result by accessing `_`.

Comment: From the docs for `timeit` :  "In cell mode (%%timeit) the statement in the first line is used as setup code (executed but not timed) and the body of the cell is timed.  The cell body has access to any variables created in the setup code." https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/4581d8b93c42014c0c232ac5de169dad053ea809/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L876

Comment: Additionally, if you add `-q` the you don't the normal output.

Answer (score 1):

> PS: this is in an ipython notebook if that makes a diff.

No it does not.

On dev there is te `%%capture` cell magic.
The other way would be to modify the timeit magic to return value instead of printing, or use the timeit module itself. Patches welcomed.