# Capture the result of an IPython magic function

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

I'm trying to capture the resulting object of IPython Notebook magic function. Specifically `%timeit`

So the following code...

```
import time
def say_hello(n):
    time.sleep(n)
    print "hello"

t = %timeit say_hello(5)
```

Prints to stdout:

```
1 loops, best of 3: 5 s per loop
```

However, I'd like to capture the result of `%timeit say_hello(5)` in the variable `t`.

A resulting object called [`TimeitResult`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/4581d8b93c42014c0c232ac5de169dad053ea809/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L65) is generated by `%timeit`, but I can't figure out how to access it from within a Notebook.

I'd like a cleaner solution than having to manually capture stdout using `sys.stdout` tricks (this code will be part of a presentation so I'm trying to keep it as straight forward as possible). Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the string of the output, or the TimeitResult object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you capture the output of ipython's magic methods? (timeit)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310752/can-you-capture-the-output-of-ipythons-magic-methods-timeit)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the source file you linked to, the docstring shows the options for running the timeit magic function; one of which is returning an object result:

```
-o: return a TimeitResult that can be stored in a variable to inspect
        the result in more details.
```

So, if you run

```
obj = %timeit -o somefunc()
```

`obj` will reference the result object that was returned (hint: use tab completion on the object, that will show you the attributes it has).

Comment: Awesome, was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Is there any documentation of the `TimeitResult` object so that I don't have to use the tab completion trick and figure out all attributes myself?

Comment: Couldn't find any official docs, but the docstring in the [source](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/61a4f1f7c11c30372fed53d6c3a90db2f692109f/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L66) shows all of the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

An example of consuming the TimeItResult output:

```
myarray = (3,2,1)
sorttime = %timeit -n1 -r3 -o myarray.sort() 
print(sorttime.best)
```

Look here for the other TimeItResult attributes: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.execution.html

Answer (score 1):

Complementing @dsemi's answer: Use `-o` to save the `timeit` result into a variable, e.g.:

```
obj = %timeit -o somefunc()
```

The docstring documentation of the `TimeitResult` when using tab completion shows the available attributes:

```
Object returned by the timeit magic with info about the run.

Contains the following attributes :

loops: (int) number of loops done per measurement
repeat: (int) number of times the measurement has been repeated
best: (float) best execution time / number
all_runs: (list of float) execution time of each run (in s)
compile_time: (float) time of statement compilation (s)
```