# How to store the result from %%timeit cell magic?

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

I can't figure out how to store the result from cell magic - `%%timeit`? I've read:

1. [Can you capture the output of ipython's magic methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310752/can-you-capture-the-output-of-ipythons-magic-methods-timeit)
2. [Capture the result of an IPython magic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289437/capture-the-result-of-an-ipython-magic-function)

and in this questions answers only about line magic. In line mode (`%`) this works:

```
In[1]: res = %timeit -o np.linalg.inv(A)
```

But in cell mode (`%%`) **it does not**:

```
In[2]: res = %%timeit -o 
       A = np.mat('1 2 3; 7 4 9; 5 6 1')
       np.linalg.inv(A)
```

It simply executes the cell, no magic. Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm using IPython 5.1.0

Comment: Thanks for not only referencing related questions, but also summarizing how they are relevant. You'd be surprised (or not) by how many people do not have this as a built in reflex when they have a question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `_` variable (stores the last result) after the `%%timeit -o` cell and assign it to some reusable variable:

```
In[2]: %%timeit -o 
       A = np.mat('1 2 3; 7 4 9; 5 6 1')
       np.linalg.inv(A)
Out[2]: blabla
        <TimeitResult : 1 loop, best of 3: 588 µs per loop>

In[3]: res = _

In[4]: res
Out[4]: <TimeitResult : 1 loop, best of 3: 588 µs per loop>
```

---

I don't think it's a bug because cell mode commands must be the first command in that cell so you can't put anything (not even `res = ...`) in front of that command.

However you still need the `-o` because otherwise the `_` variable contains `None`.

Comment: And that `res` has a number of attributes, which you can see with `res.<tab>` or `vars(res)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just care about the output of the cell magic, e.g. for recording purposes - and you don't need the extra metadata included in the TimeitResult object, you could also just combine it with %%capture:

```
%%capture result
%%timeit

A = np.mat('1 2 3; 7 4 9; 5 6 1')
np.linalg.inv(A)
```

Then you can grab the output from result.stdout, which will yield whatever the output of the cell is - including the timing result.

```
print(result.stdout)

'26.4 us +- 329 ns per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)\n'
```

This works for arbitrary cell magic, and can work as a fallback if the underscore solution isn't working.