# How do I assign the result of iPython profiler %%prun -r to a variable?

Tags: python, profiling, ipython, ipython-magic

In the [docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html) of the iPython magic functions it says:

> Usage, in cell mode:
>       %%prun [options] [statement] code... code...
>
> In cell mode, the additional code lines are appended to the (possibly
>   empty) statement in the first line. Cell mode allows you to easily
>   profile multiline blocks without having to put them in a separate
>   function.
>
> Options:
>   -r    return the pstats.Stats object generated by the profiling. This object has all the information about the profile in it, and you can
>   later use it for further analysis or in other functions.

But it doesn't give any examples of how to use the `-r` option. How do I associate the pstats.Stats object to a variable? using the cell profiler?

**edit:**

**This is not a duplicate because I specifically ask about cell mode, the other questions are about line magic functions.** Thomas K answers my question by saying it is not possible. That should be allowed as an answer to my question here which is not an answer to the other questions.

Comment: Your answer is there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310752/can-you-capture-the-output-of-ipythons-magic-methods-timeit

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a way to capture a returned value from a cell magic - that only works with line magics.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas K . If you write an answer explaining that I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a way to capture a returned value from a cell magic. With a line magic you can do:

```
a = %prun -r ...
```

But cell magics have to start at the beginning of the cell, with nothing before them.